# Owin Authentication Taking Too Long

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Owin Authentication process is taking less than 8 secs when running locally but on deployment it gets timed out. This is the Token Generator that i have implemented

```
ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);
context.Validate(ticket);
```

My DBContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").HasKey<Int32>(r => r.Id);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin").HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").HasKey(r => new{ r.IDNumber, r.UserName});
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User").HasKey<string>(r => r.UserName);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    }
```

My DBContext Constructor

```
   public CrestfineContext():
        base("Default", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }
```

And my Web.Config

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="Default" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Can't quite figure out why the Login process takes so long on the server.

**EDIT**

I have noticed this line of code takes too Long during execution

```
  User user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

I have published my application with Execute Code First Migration set to true. I have seeded an admin to the database but it doesn't return anything just takes  a lot  of execution time.

This my UserManager Class

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<User, string>
{
    public AppUserManager(IUserStore<User, string> store)
        :base(store)
    {

    }

    public static AppUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var dbcontext = context.Get<CrestfineContext>();
        var manager = new AppUserManager(new UserStore<User>(dbcontext));

         return manager;
    }

}
```

I've  also noted that CreateAsync takes too long

```
  IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Comment: What is the timeout? What else is server doing?

Comment: Its giving the response of Timed Out only error code 500

Comment: Can you profile it and see what's going on?  even 8s is far too long IMO

Comment: That's standard since i have 2 projects running so start up takes a while

Comment: Assuming you're using some form of DI, you haven't got the Context lifetime defined as Transient or something have you?  you need to work out precisely what takes the time - opening the DB, generating ticket, etc...  very hard to tell really from what info there is here.

Comment: If this be the case how come locally the process runs smoothly... I actually thought there was a problem in my code

Comment: I have noticed  User user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password); is taking too long during execution

Comment: I might be forced to delete the whole app service and start over

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Azure doesn't support Seeding of IdentityUser(**MY ASSUMPTION**). Since am trying to login to a seeded IdentityUser the method

```
 await usermanager.FindAsync(username,password)
```

Never seem's to find the User. However, this doesn't explain why register method doesn't work...

```
 await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)
```

However, all this arose when i published and i did specify execute code first migration.

So, I need an Admin User so now I've published the web api with Execute First Migration disabled. To my Register method this is what I've done..(Pathetic Solution).

```
     if(user.UserName == "xxx@****.com")
     {
        var rolemanager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new CrestfineContext()));
        var manager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new CrestfineContext()));

        rolemanager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
     }
```

Am Still hoping for a real solution.